# js writing a function of repeating codes

Tags: javascript, function

So, i have following js:

```
}else if (name== pac + 'steve/'){
    var cat_id = '42';
    CAT_L('steve');
}else if (curret_url == pac + 'mike/'){
    var cat_id = '43';
    CAT_L('mike');
}else if (curret_url == pac + 'sean/'){
    var cat_id = '44';
    CAT_L('sean');
}
```

Here , the only thing that are changing is name and number.

I am having a hard time coming up with a function to reuse the repeating code like this.

Could someone one help me how to come up with a function to simply repeat the same code?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show me a sample example? Thanks

Comment: what's the content of `pac`?

Comment: it's a simple domain `var pac = 'example.com/';`

Comment: I think you cant escape whole of it. But i suggest that you should use `switch` statement for this kind of scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like:

```
var valMap = {
  'steve': '42',
  'mike':'43',
  'sean': '44'
};

var name = curret_url.slice(pac.length);
cat_id = valMap[name];
CAT_L(name);
```

Comment: Thank you. Learned something new :)

Comment: well you can replace `if` conditions with `map`. `if` statements lets you execute one condition at a time but `map` will execute all of them. `map` is useful if you are looping and then calling that function otherwise it makes no sense.

Comment: @HarryBomrah I disagree, for starters, `map` is not meant for looping, that is what `array` is for, that aside, this way things are more concise since all cases do similar stuff...

Comment: guys, you're talking about different things. mido talks about a map like in mapping keys to values, Harry seems to talks about `Array.prototype.map`.

Comment: @mido, I would add a check to ensure, that `current_url.startsWith(pac) && name in valMap`. Just to take care of possibly ambigious or false inputs (values in the variables)

Answer (score 2):

you could use regex to extract the name:-

```js
var curret_url = "/foomike/"

var obj = {
  steve: '42',
  mike: '43',
  sean: '44'
};

var val = /\/foo(\w+)/.exec(curret_url); // pac=/foo

if (val.length && obj.hasOwnProperty(val[1])) {
  var cat_id = obj[val[1]];
  alert(val[1]);
  alert(cat_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All great solutions, here is my longer generic way... :)

```
var pac = "",
    CAT_L = function(){};

function Record(pac, config, callback) {

    var key;
    for (key in config) {
        this[pac + key] = (function(key) {
                return function() {
                    return callback.call(this, key, config[key]);
                }
            })(key);
    }

    return this;

};

Record.prototype.get = function(key) {
    return valMap[key].call(this);
}

valMap = new Record(pac, {
  'steve': '42',
  'mike':'43',
  'sean': '44'

}, function(key, val) {
    cat_id = val;
    CAT_L(key);
});


valMap.get(pac + 'steve');
```